# Liferay- Display portlet content(title) in breadcrumb?

Tags: liferay

I have created a custom portlet and which displays some content such as title,description etc.
So I want my title to be displayed in the breadcrumb?
How do I proceed for this?

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried if this is still accurate, but can you try [Alexey's](http://www.emforge.net/web/akakunin/blogs/-/blogs/249105) suggestion of using

```
PortalUtil.addPortletBreadcrumbEntry(request, title, url);
```

with the given configuration there for liferay-portlet.xml

```
<private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
```